# How to call method from another component angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm newbie with angular2 that's why i need help 
i'm creating multi-step form and i need to call method from another component 
I have SellComponent in this component template i have

```
<sell-wizard>
  <sell-wizard-step></sell-wizard-step>
</sell-wizard>
```

And i have to call method which is located in WizardComponent
Below codes from components

**WizardComponent**

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
selector: 'sell-wizard',
template: "
<ng-content></ng-content>
<div
  class="my-wizard__footer">
  <button
    [style.visibility]="isOnFirstStep() ? 'hidden' : 'visible'"
    (click)="stepChange.emit(step - 1)">
    Previous
  </button>
  {{step}} / {{steps}}
  <button
    *ngIf="!isOnFinalStep()"
    (click)="stepChange.emit(step + 1)">
    Next
  </button>
  <button
    *ngIf="isOnFinalStep()"
    (click)="finish.emit(step + 1)">
    {{finishText}}
  </button>
</div>",
})
export class WizardComponent {
@Input() finishText = 'Finish';
@Input() step = 1;
@Output() finish = new EventEmitter();
@Output() stepChange = new EventEmitter();
private steps = 0;
private isOnFinalStep = () => this.step === this.steps;
private isOnFirstStep = () => this.step === 1;

public addStep() {
  const newSteps = this.steps + 1;
  this.steps = newSteps;
  return newSteps;
}}
```

**WizardStepComponent**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { WizardComponent } from './wizard.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'sell-wizard-step',
  host: {
    '[style.display]': 'isCurrent ? "block" : "none"',
  },
  template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`,
})
export class WizardStepComponent {
private isCurrent;
private step;

constructor(
  private parent:WizardComponent
  ) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.step = this.parent.addStep();

  this.isCurrent = this.step === this.parent.step;

  this.parent.stepChange.subscribe(step => {
    this.isCurrent = this.step === step;
  });
 }
}
```

**SellComponent**

```
import { Component, Input} from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'sell',
  templateUrl: 'sell.component.html'
})
export class SellComponent  {
  private step = 1;

  constructor(){}
}
```

So in this SellComponent view i tried to call method from WizardComponent

```
<button type="button" (click)="stepChange.emit(step + 1)">next</button>
```

And it says `Cannot read property 'stepChange' of undefined`
How do i can call fucntion from another component? 
Thanks for help

Comment: You can access the `WizardComponent` in your `SellComponent` by declaring a property on the `SellComponent`: `@ViewChild(WizardComponent) wizard;` And then emit an event by accessing the `wizard.stepChange`.

Comment: Wow i'm very happy :) 
Add it like answer ill mark 
Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: You are welcome to add it as an answer with your own code to provide better context. I am a newbie in Angular and am not sure if what I suggested is the best possible solution. Glad it was helpful, though! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Found solution. Thanks to [0x2D9A3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/186787/0x2d9a3)

We can access the `WizardComponent` in our SellComponent by declaring a property on the `SellComponent: @ViewChild(WizardComponent) wizard;` And then emit an event by accessing the `wizard.stepChange.`